# How to access methods through from another class and create object

Tags: javascript, class, oop

New to OOP Javascript! I have 2 classes, Order and Customer. I have a method getName(). I want customer as one of my properties in the Order class. I have created objects for both but can't seem to access the customer name in the order object.

*Customer.js*

```
class Customer{
constructor(id, name, address,creditCard) {
this._id=id;
this._name=name;
this._address=address;
this._creditCard=creditCard;
}

getName(){
    return this._name;
}
}
```

*Order.js*

```
class Order {
customer;
constructor(id, date) {
  this._id = id;
 this._date=date;

this.customer=new Customer();
}

getNameCustomer() {
  
 return this.customer.getName();
}
 }
```

*data.js*

```
  const customer1 = new Customer(123,"John","123 E Cookie St",'xxxx xxxx xxxx 1223');

   const order1= new Order(801,'January 12, 2021 01:15:00',customer1.getNameCustomer() );

  let orders=[order1];
```

Comment: You are calling `getNameCustomer` method on `customer1` which doesn't exist. You should use `customer1.getName()`...

Comment: This doesn't make sense `this.customer = new Customer();` without passing the data required by the `Customer`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getNameCustomer` method on `customer1` which doesn't exist. You should use

```
customer1.getName()
```

But you can do better if you pass the `customer` object in the `Order` class and make it a property as:

```js
class Customer {
  constructor(id, name, address, creditCard) {
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._address = address;
    this._creditCard = creditCard;
  }

  getName() { return this._name; }
}

class Order {
  constructor(id, date, customer) {
    this._id = id;
    this._date = date;
    this._customer = customer;
  }

  getNameCustomer() { return this._customer.getName(); }
}

const customer1 = new Customer(123, "John", "123 E Cookie St", "xxxx xxxx xxxx 1223");

const order1 = new Order(801, "January 12, 2021 01:15:00", customer1);

console.log(order1);
console.log(order1.getNameCustomer());
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand!